# twine not found (-bash: twine: command not found)

Tags: python, pip, pypi, twine

I am trying to use twine to publish my first python package on pypi (of course will add on test-pypi first).

I followed the official guideline on https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/.

But for some reason, twine is not found or not properly installed.

I installed twine using:

```
pip install twine
```

"pip list" says twine is installed on pip.

After I upgraded twine and everything, when I tried to run:

```
twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

then it says that twine is not found at all:

```
-bash: twine: command not found .
```

My system is mac (high sierra) and I am using python2.7 by conda. Pip is also configured to conda python:

```
>>pip -V 
>>pip 10.0.1 from /anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Does `python -m twine` instead of just `twine` work? (This isn't a complete answer, it's a question for debugging information—but if it works, it's also a workaround you can use until you get things fixed.)

Comment: Because pip installed it, does not mean it exists on the PATH

Comment: Use `pip show -f twine` to list all files belonging to package. This will show you the relative path to the executable (smth like `../../bin/twine`). Combine it with the path printed in the `Location:` line to get the full path to the bin dir. Then add the dir to `PATH`: `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bin twine -V` should run fine. Afterwards, persist `PATH` changes in the `.bash_profile` by adding the lines `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bin` and `export PATH`. Restart the terminal and you're good to go.

Comment: @abarnert your workaround works for me now. Thank you!

Comment: @hoefling I added the path as you suggested and confirmed that the path is added to that location as I just checked by 'echo $PATH'. Still twine gives me no command found... :(

Comment: Can you paste the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: `/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/peterpark/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. The location was `/Users/peterpark/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: @hoefling When I added the path, I did `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bin` instead of `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bin twine -V` because that also gave me `-bash: twine: command not found`

Comment: You did not what I suggested, that's why it didn't work. Take the `site-packages` dir and the relative path of the executable and resolve it against the location dir. Example: location `/foo/bar/site-packages`, executable `../../bin/twine`. The dir to add to `PATH` is `/foo/bin` (two levels up from `site-packages`, then descend into `bin`). Remove the `site-packages` dir from `PATH`, add the right dir and it will work.

Comment: Based on the location path, the correct dir should be `/Users/peterpark/.local/bin`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*`

Answer (score 2):

Based on @hoefling comments run

```
pip show twine
```

That will list all files that belong to the `twine` package. It will output something like this:

> ```
> Name: twine
> Version: 1.12.1
> Summary: Collection of utilities for publishing packages on PyPI
> Home-page: https://twine.readthedocs.io/
> Author: Donald Stufft and individual contributors
> Author-email: donald@stufft.io
> License: Apache License, Version 2.0
> Location: /Users/hakuna.matata/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> Requires: pkginfo, readme-renderer, tqdm, requests, requests-toolbelt, setuptools
> Required-by:
> ```

Note the first file under `Files` which is `../../../bin/twine` and `Location: /Users/hakuna.matata/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`. Of course your user name will replace 'hakuna.matata'

That will lead to a path to package executable at `/Users/hakuna.matata/.local/bin` which you can add it to your `.bash_profile` as 
`export PATH="/Users/hakuna.matata/.local/bin:$PATH"`

Then, either restart terminal or

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command:

```bash
python -m twine upload dist/*
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation describing how the command solves the problem.