# pip: why doesn't twine command show up sometimes

Tags: python, bash, pip, twine

I installed twine using the user flag (user scheme, according to the documentation):

```
pip install --user twine
```

But I can't use it as a command. For e.g. if I do:

```
twine --version
```

It gives me (this is obvious):

```
-bash: twine: command not found
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451966/twine-not-found-bash-twine-command-not-found) similar post, but could not find any satisfactory answer (answer is not accepted).

I know I can use:

```
python3 -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

According to one of the answers.

But, my question is why it doesn't show up?

I checked the twine `setup.py` and found that it using the `entry_points` (which helps in setting the `twine command`). In my assumption, the `setup.py` is being ignored as it `pip` using `wheel` and not `sdist` during the installation (or to download the package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the command

```
twine --version
```

shell tries to find `twine` binary or script in `$PATH`. If it cannot find the script it emits the error `-bash: twine: command not found`. This means that `pip` has installed `twine` into a directory not in the `$PATH`. Find out where `pip` has installed it using the command

```
pip show --files twine
```

and add the directory to the `$PATH`.

For the command

```
python3 -m twine --version
```

shell finds `python3` and `python3 -m` looks for **a module** `twine`, not a script. `python3 -m` looks for the module in `sys.path`, a completely different search path.